# Adding share links for YouTube, Medium, Instagram, and Discord in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, share

I'm working on a Vue.js project and trying to add share links for various social media platforms. Currently, I have implemented share links for Twitter, Facebook, and Telegram, but I'm facing difficulties with YouTube, Medium, Instagram, and Discord also the telegram one is not working.
Current Implementation (Snippet from my code):

javascript

```
shareOnSocialMedia(link) {
    const currentURL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);

    switch (link.name) {
        case 'X':
            const twitterShareLink = `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=${currentURL}`;
            window.open(twitterShareLink, '_blank');
            break;

        case 'Facebook':
            const facebookShareLink = `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${currentURL}`;
            window.open(facebookShareLink, '_blank');
            break;

        case 'Telegram':
            const telegramShareLink = `https://t.me/share/url?url=${currentURL}`;
            window.open(telegramShareLink, '_blank');
            break;

        // Other cases for YouTube, Medium, Instagram, and Discord needed
        // ...

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly implement share links for YouTube, Medium, Instagram, and Discord within my project. Any advice, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!